# javascript form validation for file upload

Tags: javascript, forms, validation

I have a form which includes 3 textfields so users can upload files. They must choose to upload at least 1 file and files must be jpg, png, pdf. I am trying to validate this using javascript and check if user is selected at least 1 file and the format is correct before uploading I have the following code but it dont work. I hope someone can help thanks.

My current code:

```
 function validate_ext() {
    var filename = document.getElementById("file1").value;
    var filename2 = document.getElementById("file2").value;

    var ext = getExt(filename);
    var ext2 = getExt(filename2);
    if((ext == "pdf") || (ext=="PDF") || (ext=="jpg") || (ext=="jpeg") || (ext=="png") || (ext=="PNG"))
        return true;
    alert("Please upload files in correct format only.");
    return false;

    if(filename2!=''){

     if((ext2 == "pdf") || (ext2=="PDF") || (ext2=="jpg") || (ext2=="jpeg") || (ext2=="png") || (ext2=="PNG"))
        return true;
    alert("Please upload files in correct format only.");
    return false;
    }
}


function getExt(filename) {
    var dot_pos = filename.lastIndexOf(".");
    if(dot_pos == -1)
        return "";
    return filename.substr(dot_pos+1).toLowerCase();
}
```

Comment: Please be more specific than "it dont(sp) work"

Comment: A thing I noticed: you are converting the extension to lower case, yet comparing to upper case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(test [here](http://jsfiddle.net/cambraca/XugLp/2)):

```
function getExt(filename) {
    var dot_pos = filename.lastIndexOf(".");
    if (dot_pos == -1) {
        return "";
    }
    return filename.substr(dot_pos + 1).toLowerCase();
}

function validate_ext() {
    var filename = document.getElementById("file1").value;
    var filename2 = document.getElementById("file2").value;
    var ext = getExt(filename);
    var ext2 = getExt(filename2);
    if (!((ext == "pdf") || (ext == "jpg") || (ext == "jpeg") || (ext == "png"))) {
        alert("Please upload files in correct format only.");
        return false;
    }

    if (filename2 != "") {
        if (!((ext2 == "pdf") || (ext2 == "jpg") || (ext2 == "jpeg") || (ext2 == "png"))) {
            alert("Please upload files in correct format only.");
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

You had a couple of errors.

- What `sjums` said about the extension being converted to lower case, you don't need to compare to upper case strings.
- If the first check is `true`, your code just returns when it should run the second check.

I also added a `return true` at the end, so the function returns this value only if it passed *all* the validations.

Comment: thank you for your answer. i would like to make so that users should choose at least one file so it shouldnt be mandatory for them to select 2 files. how can I validate this. Thanks.

Comment: Well, the code kinda does that already, because for `file1` you don't have the `if (filename1 != "")` that you have on `file2`.

Comment: Thank you for your input and answer. Do you think I am doing it using javascript is secure enough or I should do some other extra checks?

Comment: You should definitely do these checks again in the server. It's easy for an attacker to skip this JS. You should at least have a maximum file size, and ideally check the mime type too (i.e. only accept "image/jpg", "image/png", etc). I don't know what server-side technology you're using, but most have libraries that do all this for you.